# Java execution flow engine

Tags: java

I'm looking for a simple execution flow engine in Java. I look for something as simple as possible, without any support of BPEL. It should support defining flows, steps and may be transactions in XML.

The only thing that was similar to that was javasteps, which looks outdated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Drools/JBpm by Jboss is something you could explore.  Drools Flow (as the other answer states) is probably what your after.

Comment: Thanks, yet these options are an overkill for my needs. I need something much simpler. No need for BPM support. I don't need a workflow engine, just a simple flow engine.

Comment: Sorry, the Drools Flow is the 'lighter weight' part of this combination, it might still be overkill for your needs.  I'll edit my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Drools Flow](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-flow.html)? I have not worked with it myself, but it is said to be mature and versatile

Answer (score 0):

If it is for managing page flow, have you considered Spring Web Flow (http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/)?